# Django JSON field. 'module' object has no attribute 'JSONField'

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django and was frustrated by creating a json field in a model.  I was trying to create a json field in my model but got error: 'module' object has no attribute 'JSONField'. Here is my class in models.py:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.JSONField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

I am using django 1.9.8 and postgresql 9.2.13. 
I need the table created in postgresql db has a column with JSON type. How can I do that in the model class? 
Thank you!

Comment: drop the models infront of JSONField

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no `JSONField` in models. But there's a handy `jsonfield` package available to use `JSONField` in Django models. To install the package, do:

```
pip install jsonfield
```

Once installed, do:

```
from jsonfield import JSONField
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
question_text = JSONField(max_length=200)
pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

Comment: This will work. But you lose awesome stuff that comes with Postgres-locked Django's JSONField like indexes and queries on json data.

Comment: @Mikhail Pyrev, so I should upgrade postgresql instead of using the jsonfield model? thanks!

Comment: Yes, core functionality is always better choice than third party lib. :)

Comment: My problem with the Postgres extension, is that it doesn't work with sqlite which I use for development. I plan to use this proposed solution and change the column datatype from `TEXT` to `jsonb` like:
`ALTER TABLE zfsb_api_paymentevent ALTER COLUMN response TYPE jsonb USING response::jsonb;`

Answer (score 25):

There's no `JSONField` in `models` module, you need to:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = JSONField()
```

Django doc about [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield).

Comment: This will not work anyway in OP's case, because Django's JSONField uses `jsonb` type that only present in PostgreSQL >=9.4.

Comment: @Shang wang, I got NameError: name 'JSONField' is not defined.

Comment: @Mikhail Pyrev, I think I should upgrade to PostgreSql 9.4.

Answer (score 19):

## Django 3.1 update

Starting with Django 3.1, the `JSONField` is now available for all database backends.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.JSONField

Answer (score 1):

Changing the import statement should fix your problem (it helped me):

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb import JSONField
```

So JSONField is located in jsonb module now.