# How to install JSONFields properly?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-jsonfield

I just wanted to upload my django project on digitalocean, but ran into multiple problems, of which I can not solve the last one.

I am using a restframework. After getting an error, that there is

```
No module named rest_framework.views
```

I installed it, but get the next error:

```
AttributeError at /
'module' object has no attribute 'JSONField'
```

Simply installing JSONField does not change anything. 
I think it still has to do with the restframework module.

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py in <module>
ModelSerializer.serializer_field_mapping[postgres_fields.JSONField] = JSONField
```

I have been trying to solve it for hours already but nothing helps...

Has someone had the same problem or knows how to fix it?

Thanks a lot and kind regards
[image: views.py]

[image: settings.py]

[image: error p1]
[image: error p2]

Comment: Could you show how you import the JSONField ? your INSTALLED_APPS and just to be sure do you use a postgres ?

Comment: And show what you're doing to "install" rest_framework.views and JSONField.

Comment: i just added sceenshots of my project to the post. thanks so much for your help guys. Its really getting frustrating over here -.-

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Djano JSON field. 'module' object has no attribute 'JSONField'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38513827/djano-json-field-module-object-has-no-attribute-jsonfield)

Comment: saw the post already but none of the measures solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I guess the error is the way you do:

```
import JSONField
```

Just delete that line.

Then you won't be able to use it because you're using sqlite3. here's a [tutorial](https://goonan.io/setting-up-postgresql-on-os-x-2/) to use postgres.